# Css position text in center

Tags: css, centering

I'm making a vertical split in a div between image and text. I want to center the `<p>` element vertically(responsive solution). I don't want to use table. Using flexbox causes the image to shrink. Keep in mind that the divs are relative. How to position the texts in the middle vertically?

```css
    *{
            overflow-x:hidden !important;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  transition:1s;
}
body{
background-color:black;
}
.r > img {
  float: right;
width:50%;
    
}

.r {
  overflow: auto;
  color:white;
  height:auto;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  
}
p{
    margin:1vmax;
box-sizing:border-box;
font-size:4vmax;
   position: relative;

}
.l > img {
  float: left;
  width:50%;
}

.l {
  overflow: auto;
  color:white;
  height:auto;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="r">
        <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/00000b.jpg&text=Test+Image' alt>
        <p style='txt'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. et dictum interdum... </p>
    </div>
    <div class="l">
        <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/00000b.jpg&text=Test+Image' alt>
        <p style='txt'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. et dictum interdum... </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

. Some other solutions don't work well with a second div of similar type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `transform: translateY();` function inside css to your `<p>` elements. this is the code you should have:

```
p {
    margin:1vmax;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-size:4vmax;
    position: relative;

    transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

`translateY(5O%)` will move your `<p>` element exactly to the desired place you were talking about, as long as you don't give the `<div>` a specific height

Comment: Transform for layout is a bit of a hacky approach, you want your layout to rely on the box model for stability. Other undesired side effects may come from using translate combined with other code down the road.

Comment: I agree, there are better solutions for this problem

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward with flexbox once you put a wrapper div around your `img` elements. Important bits are setting the `flex` property on flex children...

```
flex: 0 0 50%; /* dont grow, dont shrink, start at 50% width */
```

...and telling the image to respect its container and retain aspect ratio:

```
.img-wrap img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}
.r,
.l {
  display: flex;
}
.r {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.img-wrap,
p {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.img-wrap img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="r">
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/00000b.jpg&text=Test+Image' alt>
    </div>
    <p style='txt'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. et dictum interdum... </p>
  </div>
  <div class="l">
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/00000b.jpg&text=Test+Image' alt>
    </div>
    <p style='txt'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. et dictum interdum... </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using `display: inline-block`.

```css
*{
        overflow-x:hidden !important;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  transition:1s;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
background-color:black;
}

img, p{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
}
.r {
  overflow: auto;
  color:white;
  height:auto;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  direction: rtl;
}
p{
  color: #fff;
margin:1vmax;
font-size:4vmax;
direction: ltr;
text-align: center;
  width: 47%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="r">
    <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/00000b.jpg&text=Test+Image' alt>
    <p class='txt'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. et dictum interdum... </p>
</div>
<div class="l">
    <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/00000b.jpg&text=Test+Image' alt>
    <p class='txt'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. et dictum interdum... </p>
</div>
</body>
```